# Existe alguma maneira de definir um max-height de um elemento igual ao tamanho da janela, com CSS puro?

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho uma sidebar, que pode conter n itens numa listagem.

A minha sidebar está mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu código fonte, defini o seguinte `css` para funcionar:

```
.sidebar {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Agora a minha dúvida é: Quero que o tamanho do `max-height`, varie de acordo com o tamanho da tela. Ou seja, se o usuário redimensionar ou dependendo do tamanho do monitor do usuário, quero que a minha `sidebar` tenha o `max-height` de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

Tentei usar `max-height: 100%`, mas não deu certo.

Existe alguma maneira de definir isso com Css puro?

Se não tiver, qual é a forma mais simples de resolver esse problema?

Comment: tentou `height: 100vh` ?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Se funcionar no Google Chrome server. O problema é alguém procurar minha pergunta, querendo uma solução crossbrowser

Comment: O max-height:100% funciona, mas vai depender de como está montado o html e o css dos elementos 'pais'.

Comment: De acordo com o http://caniuse.com/#search=vh, o suporte ta razoável, até. As pessoas só vão parar de usar o IE quando nós pararmos de fazer coisas pro IE.. De qualquer maneira, vc pode seguir o approach do @GivanildoR.deOliveira, ou partir pra uma solução `flex-box`, o que é bem mais elegante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Com `position: relative;` e `position: absolute;`

Você pode simplesmente usar um `positition: absolute` no `.sidebar` e `positition: relative` no objeto pai (nomei de `.main`), note que o html e o body precisam ter `height: 100%;` e o `.main` tem que ser filho direto do body e ter `min-height: 100%`

Também adicionei `margin-left: 300px;` pra que o `.content` não fique abaixo do `.sidebar`.

Este efeito funciona bem para todos browsers mais modernos como IE8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Todavia não funciona bem no IE com *quircks-mode*, exemplo:

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
}
.main {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background: #fc0;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
    </div>
</div>
```

### Com `position: fixed;`

Você também pode querer um efeito que o sidebar acompanhe a tela, quero dizer fique fixo nela, você pode usar `position: fixed;`, a única dificuldade com ele será ajustar conforme as margens (se vier a precisar)

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background: #fc0;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
      foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
      baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
    </div>
</div>
```

### Com `display: flex;`

Sendo um app-chrome ele suporta flex o que pode facilitar, então use `display: flex;` no objeto pai (no exemplo criei um `.main`), e `flex: 1;` nos objetos filhos, isso é basicamente o sistema de ["equal height columns"](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22equal%20height%20columns%22) (ou same height columns).

Usando flex (neste exemplo o `height: 100%;` é dispensável, só adicionei pois senão poderia ser imperceptível conforme variasse o conteúdo):

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #fc0;
}
.content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="sidebar">
  foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
  foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
  foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
  foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
  foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
  foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
  foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br> foo <br>
</div>

<div class="content">
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
  baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> baz <br> 
</div>
</div>
```